# Execute script on insertion of sdcard

Tags: udev

Since I want some union mounts to be created, once a sd card is found in my system, I wrote the following udev `my.rules`:

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="mmcblk0", SUBSYSTEM=="block", \
    RUN+="touch /tmp/my_udev_rule_matched_OK"
```

Now sadly, `/tmp/my_udev_rule_matched_OK` never appears on my system. Is there anything wrong with the matching?

When I use `udevadm monitor`, I see the event fired if I plug in the sd card. And when I do `udevadm test`, `my.rules` is shown as read.
Sadly I have not yet figured out, how to get a log of the internal decisions of udev.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ACTION=="add", RUN+="touch /tmp/my_udev_rule_matched_OK"
```

Answer (score 0):

- Rename it to `99-my.rules`
- Use absolute paths:

  ```
  SUBSYSTEM=="block", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/touch /tmp/my_udev_rule_matched_OK"
  ```